# Database design for microservices

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, network-programming, microservices

I am building a back end for a web application which will be based on microservices architecture. Each microservice will be responsible for managing tasks related to a specific module only and will have its own local database.There can be more than one microservice for one module.For example

A customer module will have its own microservice and the microservice will have local database to persist the customer data.
A order module will like wise have its own local database to persist order records.

I am thinking of managing data persistance using event driven architecture but I want to know if there is some database which can be useful for this implementation ( Cassandra maybe ? )

I am open to any suggestions :)

Comment: If you properly abstract your application, then decision about which database will use you can take on the later stage of your development.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the application itself. If you want to use a application-aware database you can use a NoSQL database like cassandra. If you just want to model and store data on a ER basis you can use some relational database (e.g. Oracle).
Nevertheless, Cassandra should be deployed as a clustered database and so is not suitable to use as a local database.

To advise you with more appropriate database to your context you have to give more info about your "problem", for instance, how many concurrent users you will support, how many requests per user, how much data you have?